# How to change source and target table connection details in oracle ODI without disturbing the existing interface?

Tags: oracle, interface, oracle-data-integrator

I work on a Data warehouse(Oracle database 10g) that uses Oracle ODI 10g as an ETL tool.
As part of digital transformation, we are migrating all applications and databases to cloud. This is will cause all the source & target tables in the ODI interfaces to change. The tables will remain same but their connection strings will be changed as the entire data warehouse will move to cloud.

I want to know how to update the connection details of all source and target tables in ODI without impacting existing ODI interfaces and packages in any way.

Is there a easy way to just update/change the connection details for all tables from topology manager of oracle ODI? I do not want to re-create all interfaces as it wont be a feasible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the connection details can be done on the JDBC tab of the Data Servers in the Topology manager.

Each datastore belongs to a Model. A Logical Schema is set for each model in the Model Definition. Logical Schemas are tied to Physical Schemas through Contexts. When executing a mapping we have to specify which context is used. That way at runtime the Logical Schema is translated to the Physical Schema.

Comment: Thankyou this helps a lot! I will plan to change the JDBC connections of tables as suggested.! However there is one more challenge. One of our target systems is Oracle Hyperion which stores data in cubes. The requirement is to write that data to a normal table in database and send a CSV file to Oracle Hyperion. Can I change the 'technology' of the Oracle Hyperion target Objects to be a database table? Is it possible? or I will have to re-create all the interfaces (and there are a LOT of interfaces).

Comment: No, you would have to change the target datastore everywhere. It might be possible to automate some changes using the ODI SDK but I don't know if that's possible in ODI 10g. ODI 10g is not supported anymore, I would suggest to upgrade to 12c.

Comment: Okay. Thankyou for you advice.